# how to prevent nan values while using grouper groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I apply this code to my data frame, and it keeps bringing Nan values that weren't there before. There is no Nan values in the df at first. It works fine in small dataframes but the bigger dataframe gets, the more Nan values it returns. I got almost 30k Nan for a 130k df.

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="10min")).mean()
```

How can I solve this Nan value problem? Or any suggestions for a different method? I need to increase my 1 min data bin to 10 min without losing data.

Comment: Probably you have some non-numeric values in your data frame. So the mean() function fails. Does not necessarily need to be nan values

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I seperated the numeric values as a different df and applied it again but there were still nan values, and it was the same amount with categorical df returned. what else might be the reason u think? and is there any other functions that you know that I can use instead? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it is all numeric? You can also try the following: .mean(numeric_only=True)

Comment: Hi again, yes I'm very sure:) it gives even more Nan values when df gets bigger. It reaches around 30% of total df length.